# text line alignments on different window sizes

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm working on a login  window that has to support multiple resolutions.
within that window there's a long line of text in different colors.

```
<TextBlock   
    Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"
    TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    TextAlignment="Center">
        <Run  
            Text="{Binding MsgA}"
        />
        <Run                        
            Foreground="#FFFFFF"                      
            FontFamily="{StaticResource CentralSansBook}"                  
            Text="{Binding MsgB}"
        />
</TextBlock>
```

with this code I get this:
on Low resolutions, since I have almost half the width, I'll give up on pretty formatting and just want it to fit, so it will look like this

```
This is message A.This is
      message B
```

on HIGH resolutions I want it to look like this

```
    This is message A.
    This is message B
```

I cant figure out how to support both behaviors.

Comment: If i were you, i would write a trigger (inside the your textblock) for Window resolution (whick is static, so you can refer (with x:static) to it inside binding) which will change the TextWrapping value.

Comment: that sounds like it might work, any chance you got a reference link?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see all you need is just paste a line break before second message for high resolution. So I would do it in View layer with value converter:

```
public class NewLineInsCnv : IValueConverter
{
    public bool InsertNewLine { get; set; } = IsHighResolution();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (InsertNewLine && value is string st)
        {
            return Environment.NewLine + st;
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("One way only conversion");
    }

    private static bool IsHighResolution()
    {
        return true;//Check
    }
}

<TextBlock   
        Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        TextAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.Resources>
            <local:NewLineInsCnv x:Key="insertNewLineCnv"/>
        </TextBlock.Resources>
        <Run  
            Text="{Binding MsgA}"
        />
        <Run                        
            Foreground="#FFFFFF"                      
            FontFamily="{StaticResource CentralSansBook}"                  
            Text="{Binding MsgB, Converter={StaticResource insertNewLineCnv}}"
        />
    </TextBlock>
```

If necessary you could make `InsertNewLine` a dependency property.